Can I get a resonance frequency from FFT power spectrum result?
I'm going through vibration analysis of cantilever by using FFT device but impact hammer input data isn't showing for some reason. So instead, I'm trying to get the resonance frequency by acceleration power spectrum obtained from FFT device. Since integration and differentiation can be simply considered as multiplying and dividing in frequency domain, I think it will show the similar shape. Is it ok to get the resonance frequency from peak of  acceleration power spectrum data?

I believe you should provide some more information on your system, setup and data. In general, it “is OK” to look for resonances through an FFT but there are a whole bunch of other things to consider, such as the window length, the sharpness of resonance (i.e. the damping of the system), other physical factors that may come into place, etc.
